# How to change values in a div created dinamically in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have some data that is being store in an array called `cards` in my component state props. 
When I get data from the API I put the results in this array and for each element of the array I render a  with the data of the respective element. One of the properties of this data is called `quantity` that always starts at 1.

The problem is, at that div, I want to increment or decrement this value of each individual  element, but I don't know how. The only way I know is to change the value in the state property using `this.setValue()`, but this is in the Component properties, not the individual element of the array.

So how can I update the value of a dinamically generated div without using setState()?

This is my div. When I click in the buttons nothing happens. Nothing is shown on the console either.

[image]

Here is my array definition:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: '',
        list: [],
        cards: [],//this will store the data from the API
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

This is the function that insert the result of the GET request into my `cards` array:

```
searchCard = () => {
    const response = axios.get("https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=".concat(this.state.value)).then(result => {
        let cardsArray = [];            
        result.data.data.map((element) => {
            element.quantity = 1;
            cardsArray.push(element)
        });
        this.setState({ cards: cardsArray });
        console.log(this.state.cards);
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

And this is my automatically generated divs:

```
addCardToPool = (element) => {
    if (element.quantity <= 3) {
        element.quantity += 1;
    }

}
removeCardFromPool=(element) => {
    if (element.quantity >= 1) {
        element.quantity -= 1;
    }
}
<div className="card-thumbnail-container">                    
                {this.state.cards.length > 0 ? //if the cards array is not empty
                    this.state.cards.map((element, key) =>
                        <div className="card-thumbnail" key={key}>
                            <div className="card-image"><img src={element.image_uris.normal} /></div>
                            <div className="quantity buttons">
                                <button className="button is-small is-danger" onClick={this.addCardToPool(element)}>Rem.</button>
                                <div><button className="button is-success is-info">Add: {element.quantity}</button></div>
                                <button className="button is-small is-info" onClick={this.removeCardFromPool(element)}>Add.</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
           :<div></div>}
    </div>
```

Comment: Make you Cards into another Component,. Don't try and do everything in 1 component.  Your Card Component can then have it's own state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One feature of React that's often over-looked is that you build components from other components, this concept is known as composition.

So in your example, rather than trying to do everything in one component, split it into 2.  Maybe called `Cards` & `Card`.

This has the advantage that `Card` will have it's own state, so becomes trivial to maintain updates.

Below is an example, it uses Hooks, but the same concept would apply if you use the component method instead,. I've also included a pretend remote database get, that then will show a please wait message.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

//pretend async get cards
function getCards() {
  return new Promise((r, x) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const cards = [
        {name:'one', qty: 1},
        {name:'two', qty: 1},
        {name:'three', qty: 1}
      ]
      r(cards);
    }, 500);
  });
}

function Card(props) {
  const [card, setCard] = useState(props.card);
  function btAdd(value) {
    return () => {
      const newQty = card.qty + value;
      if (newQty < 1 || newQty > 4) return;
      setCard({...card, qty: newQty});
    }
  }
  return <div>
    <button onClick={btAdd(-1)}>-</button>
    <div style={{margin: "0 10px", width: "70px", display: "inline-block"}}>
      {card.name} = {card.qty}</div>
    <button onClick={btAdd(+1)}>+</button>
  </div>;
}

function Cards() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getCards().then(c => setCards(c));
  }, []);
  return cards.length
    ? cards.map((card, ix) => 
      <Card key={ix} card={card}/>)
    : <div>Loading please wait..</div>;
}


ReactDOM.render(<Cards/>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="mount"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! But in my case I only needed to implement one component called `Card`. Thank you very much!